# Change password searching for ID with sha1 hash in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sha1

Im trying to change the password of a user with the following code in PHP PDO:

```
public function resetaSenha(string $senha, string $id){
            $con = $this->conexao;

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET senha = :senha WHERE id = sha1(:id)";

            $obj = $con->prepare($sql);
            $obj->bindParam(":senha", $senha);
            $obj->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $obj->execute();
        }
```

And i'm calling this function with the sha1 hash of the id 1 and the password (im doing like this for tests only):

```
    require_once("funcoes_db.php");

    $func = new FuncoesDb();
    $func->resetaSenha("05fe7461c607c33229772d402505601016a7d0ea", "356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab");
```

But it isn't working. It works if i change the query to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET senha = :senha WHERE id =:id";
```

And call the function with:

```
    `$func->resetaSenha("05fe7461c607c33229772d402505601016a7d0ea", "1")`;
```

But i'm getting the values via URL and i need them to be encrypted. Why isn't this working that way ?

Comment: It seems alright... is everything working in your sql server ?

Comment: Yes it is, it works without the sha1() in the PHP.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and ensure you use a proper cryptographic hash on the password.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a typo without realizing. The query string calls the `sha1` function on `:id`, when it should be called on `:senha` to hash the password.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET senha = :senha WHERE id = sha1(:id)";
```

should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET senha = sha1(:senha) WHERE id = :id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id column is a **varchar** type? If no, if it's an **int** auto-increment you should't use `WHERE id = sha1(:id)` in your where clause.

If you want to encrypt in URL the user id, try using base64 that you can encode and decode. Sha1 is a hashing function, you can't decode.